# more efficient way to build a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to send html for a table to an html-to-pdf converter script.  My table must be composed of the `<thead>` from table1, the `<tfoot>` from table3 and the `<tbody>` from table2.  I'm putting together the html with jQuery.  This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = $('div.dataTables_scroll').html();//so that changes don't affect the main page
    var h = $(html).find('thead')[0];
    var f = $(html).find('tfoot')[1];
    var b = $(html).find('tbody')[0];
    var newtable = $('<table></table>').append(h, f, b);
    var d = $('<div></div>').append(newtable);
    $('#foo').val(d.html()); //to see what the html looks like   
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/P4vC3/88/)'s a JSFiddle of the whole thing. It works well enough, but I think there should be a more elegant way.

Ideas?

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Diodeus: codereview appears to still be in beta. That's likely why I was not aware of its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var ctx = $( 'div.dataTables_scroll' )[0];

var html = [
    '<table>',
        '<thead>' + $( 'thead', ctx ).eq( 0 ).html() + '</thead>',
        '<tfoot>' + $( 'tfoot', ctx ).eq( 1 ).html() + '</tfoot>',
        '<tbody>' + $( 'tbody', ctx ).eq( 0 ).html() + '</tbody>',
    '</table>'
].join( '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty solid. I don't think there's a more efficient or elegant way of working with tables, really. If you want, you can rewrite it like this to make it a bit more explicit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tables = $('div.dataTables_scroll table');
    var thead = tables.eq(0).find('thead');
    var tfoot = tables.eq(1).find('tfoot');
    var tbody = tables.eq(2).find('tbody');

    var newTable = $('<table />').append(thead, tfoot, tbody);
    var result = $('<div />').append(newTable).html();

    $('#foo').val(result);
});
```

I can't say much about performance, but it's a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any real *elegance* when it comes to constructing tables. Since you are just building the one table, I would suggest that you stick to the solution you already have.

If, however, you need to construct a huge table (or multiple ones) comprised of many rows, cells, and whatever, I would suggest doing it *offline*; that is, assembling all the parts into a plain-old string buffer, and inserting it into the DOM once you have finished constructing it. That way you are not slowing down the browser by repeatedly writing to the DOM, which can be terribly expensive.

Comment: Your arguments are sound. But in this case there are extenuating circumstances. The tables that I am harvesting from are the output from DataTables (http://datatables.net/) processing of the original table. So to create a server side version I'd have to essentially replicate the DataTable plugin, at least in part, on the serverside. As well, the server script would need to be aware of any user applied modifications like filtres or sort orders.

Answer (score 0):

Making the intermediate table and div are unnecessary. Write down the information, put it where you'd like. Don't play with it in between.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $('div.dataTables_scroll');
    var html = "<table><thead>" + $target.find('thead').eq(0).html() + "</thead>";
    html += "<tbody>" + $target.find('tfoot').eq(1).html() + "</tbody>";
    html += "<tfoot>" + $target.find('tbody').eq(0).html() + "</tfoot></table>";
    $('#foo').val(html);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4vC3/88/)